# Difficult category search with Solspace Super Search

Tags: solspace, search, supersearch

I need compose search string for this condition:
Search in Home category and Cat or Dog.
I tried like this: category=53&&236+47 but in don't work

I need only search string, Without form for searching

Comment: FYI: Low Search can do this with its Categories filter: http://gotolow.com/addons/low-search/docs/filters#categories

Comment: Thanks. But project is not small and now I can't change module.
I will try in future project

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately you cannot combine AND and OR searches at this time. I recommend submitting this as a Feature Request under the specific add-on category. It'll also give other users the option to vote up the feature request, and help us prioritize features to add in upcoming versions of this add-on. :)
http://support.solspace.com/support/discussions